# In numpy, the pythonic way of changing the values of one channel

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an array with a shape of

```
(960,1920,4)
```

with values like

```
[[[  0  60   0   0]
  [  0 100   0   1]]

 [[  0 100   0   1]
  [  0  40   0   0]]]
```

What is the pythonic way of changing those 1 in the fourth channel to 255? (I could do it with some loops but I suspect that will take time and not being the best way to do it)

The result I wish to obtain is

```
[[[  0  60   0   0]
  [  0 100   0   255]]

 [[  0 100   0   255]
  [  0  40   0   0]]]
```

Note: I guess some multiplication could do in this case and that would be ok but what if instead of all 1's I have multiple non-zeros and would like to convert them to 255

Answer (score 5):

[Advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) and assignment:

```
a[a[...,3] == 1, 3] = 255
a
[[[  0  60   0   0]
  [  0 100   0 255]]

 [[  0 100   0 255]
  [  0  40   0   0]]]
```

Notice here we are using combined boolean index `a[...,3] == 1` and integer index `3` to locate the positions that need to be modified. The case is documented under [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

In this case, the combined index is equivalent to the following tuple:

```
(a[..., 3] == 1).nonzero() + (3,)
```